The trajectory of particle released from rest in a force field
If I release a particle from rest in a force field whose curl is zero everywhere, would its trajectory be independent of its mass?
In mathematical language,
$$
m\frac{d^2\vec{r}}{dt^2}=-\nabla U(x,y,z),
$$
where $U$ is a known function and ${\rm d}\vec{r}/{\rm d}t = 0$ at $t=0$.
Show that the orbit traced by $\vec{r}(t)$ is independent of the parameter $m$, or disprove it.

Please note that the initial velocity of the particle is zero !!!. This is very important.


The trajectory of a charged particle in a uniform static electric field very much depends on the mass of the particle, so your question doesn't make sense.

@Pranay The initial condition is that the particle is initially at rest. So the trajectory in a uniform field is the same

Starting at rest doesn't change the fact that the trajectory depends on the charge-to-mass ratio. This is how charge-to-mass ratio is measured in experiments.

@ Pranay In uniform field the trajectory is a ray. The velocity is dependent on mass but the trajectory is not.

A trajectory with no specification of velocity is just a path, not a trajectory.

@ David K But that is not what it says on cambridge dictionary, can you provide a source? Thanks.

@ Ted Shifrin. Thanks for your attention. I've restated the question. I hope the description is clear.

For non-technical purposes a trajectory without velocity may be acceptable. For our purposes it is not (or at least not acceptable to assume that everyone will understand you mean to disregard speed along the path when you don't say so explicitly and immediately). But the part in your question about "the orbit traced by $\vec r(t)$" is a good description of what I think you want, so let's use that.

In any case, the orbit traced by $\vec r(t)$ need not lie on a straight line in a field with zero curl, even starting from rest.

@ David K I didn't say that. Pranay is using the uniform electric field as an example. Please note "uniform"

I think reparametrizing $t\rightarrow t \sqrt m$ (or perhaps $t/\sqrt m$) should remove any dependence on $m$. More specifically, if $\vec r(t)$ is a solution to the given equation, then $\vec r(t\sqrt m)$ is a solution of the equation with $m$ set to $1$. This rescales the initial velocity by a factor of $\sqrt m$, but this doesn't matter since it is zero anyway. For this argument to work, you don't really need a curl-free force field. You just want the force to depend only on position but not on velocity (or time).

@Pranay Thanks for the valuable insight. I saw your answer about the mathematica simulation's been deleted. Did your simulation confirm that m doesn't affect the orbit?

I made a mistake in that simulation. After correcting it, it does confirm that the orbit is independent of $m$. And it is precisely for the reason in my comment above.

@Pranay Your reparameterization seems like an answer to me.

@DavidK I’ll turn my comment into an answer then.

Let $\mathbf r(t)$ be a solution to the equation
$$
m \ddot{\mathbf r}(t) = \mathbf F(\mathbf r(t)),
$$
with the initial conditions $\mathbf r(0) = \mathbf r_0$ and $\dot{\mathbf r}(0)= \mathbf 0$. Here, $\mathbf F$ depends only on the position of the particle but not on its velocity. Then, $\mathbf x(t) = \mathbf r(t\sqrt m)$ satisfies the equation
$$
\ddot{\mathbf x}(t) = m \ddot{\mathbf r}(t\sqrt m) = \mathbf F(\mathbf r(t\sqrt m)) = \mathbf F(\mathbf x(t)).
$$
which is independent of $m$. Moreover, the initial conditions are $\mathbf x(0) = \mathbf r(0) = \mathbf r_0$ and $\dot{\mathbf x}(0) = \sqrt m \dot{\mathbf r}(0) = \mathbf 0$. So $\mathbf x(t)$ defines the same "orbit" as $\mathbf r(t)$; the only difference is in the scaled parametrisation.

I am disappointed that this answer has not yet been accepted. It seems to me it answers the question perfectly.
